# Удаление метки из кластера Яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Не получается удалить выбранную метку.
    Добавляю метки следующим образом:

```
function addMarker(coordin1, coordin2, adres, nomerID) {
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
        [coordin1,coordin2],
        {balloonContentHeader: 'Метка'}, {
            id: nomerID
            });

        clusterer.add(myPlacemark, nomerID);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
        ObjectiID[nomerID] = clusterer;

    }
```

После этого вызываю функцию удаления выбранной метки:

```
function UdalitTekMetku(id) {
    // Закрывает открытый балун
    myMap.balloon.close();
    // Варианты удаления метки
1.  myMap.geoObjects.remove(clusterer.get(id));
2.  myMap.geoObjects.remove(ObjectiID[id]);
3.  clusterer.remove(ObjectiID[id]);
}
```

Цифры - это варианты попыток удаления метки.
Открытый балун закрывается, но метка не удаляется.
Помогите, кто знает проблему.

Comment: Правильно ли я устанавливаю id для метки? ID нужно устанавливать для Placemark или для clusterer?

Comment: Есть вероятность, что неправильно устанавливаю ID для метки!

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в конце `cluster.refresh()`

Comment: Не проходит. Пишет, неизвестная ошибка.